# What does this RSOD mean? - Trying to use Firepro S9100 in ML350PG8

Tags: hpe

I've bought two FirePro S9100 for my VDI enviroment.
They work perfectly fine on a DL580G7. But within a ML350PG8 I got the following Red Screens Of Death, shortly after the first Booting, when it initialize the PCIe extansions. I had clearified, that those RSOD are caused by the FirePro S9100s, unaffected, which one if both or only, and which, one is installed.

The RSOD (both show the exactly same information):

```
illegal OpCode
EAX=0000005F  EBX=00000546  ECX=00000000  EDX=00000004
EBP=0000FC2E  ESI=0001AB07  EDI=0000FC36
DS=D040       ES=0030       FS=0000       GS=0000
CS:EIP=0000:00000007        SS:ESP=0030:0000FBAE
EFLAGS=00000056
_
```

To be honest, I never before saw such an RSOD - I even didn't know, that there are RSOD.^^

Please, before someone comes with a RTFM-comment, I did, I know, they just only have listed nVidia products (but I need DP. so it got to be AMD), but since the DL580 G7 supports those cards, and the DL380 G9 theire bigger broder S9150, I expect them also to work, with G8.

Is this eventually just an Bios configuration thing, I need to change, before installing those cards?

Thx a lot
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know, what this RSOD does mean. 
But I figgured out two ways to handle it. 
(I prefer the second one!)
1.) downgrade to the oldest HP Bios and SPP Version for the ML350PG8. (With those it does work, but I didn't tested long, because I found it an unacceptable solution.
2.) Raidcontroller have to be in Slot 3, while (at least those FirePros GPUs) have to be in Slot 6 and 8.
So I still not know, why it had worked with WX9100 instead of P812 in Slot 3, but with S9100 it doesn't, so you must use the controller in Slot 3.

With the second configuration (with march SPP an 2018 BIOS) it's now working (with heavy wl) for nearly 24h.